# How to change a variable in the JavaScript without loading the JavaScript content?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a typing web game written using JS. The JS contains all the necessary definition and algorithm of the game. There is a global variable called game_mode. By altering this variable to either 0, 1 or 2, I can load different game modes on the webpage. 
My difficulty is, I can't figure out a way where I can edit game_mode before I load the JS content using HTML. If I load the JS, the JS already starts running and thus the game starts, using the game_mode hard-coded. 
Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Put the variable in the page itself instead of in the script file.

Answer (score 2):

Take all your Javascript code that you have written and put into a file, example `game.js`.  In your HTML you can import/reference the Javascript.  Before referencing it set the variable `game_mode` to the desired value.

See below.

index.html

```
<script>
    var game_mode = 2;
</script>
<script src="/game.js"> </script>
```